Issues with Link Time Optimization (LTO) on avr-gcc with ATmega328
I’m working on a project with an ATmega328 and using avr-gcc/g++. I'm trying to enable Link Time Optimization (LTO), but I’m encountering issues during linking.
Here's a simplified example:
•   Static Library: libATmega328__T_LIB.a (consists of blink.cpp and blink.cpp.obj)
•   Executable: ATmega328__T_ uses the blink() function defined in blink.cpp.obj within main.cpp.

Compiler Flags:

tools.build:cxxflags=['-mmcu=atmega328', '-O2', '-ffunction-sections',
'-fdata-sections', '-fno-exceptions', '-fno-rtti', '-flto',
'-fuse-linker-plugin', '-fno-devirtualize']

Linker Flags:

tools.build:exelinkflags=['-Wl,--gc-sections', '-flto']
tools.build:sharedlinkflags=['-Wl,--gc-sections', '-flto']

Build Environment:
AR=/opt/avr8-gnu-toolchain-linux_x86_64/bin/avr-ar
AS=/opt/avr8-gnu-toolchain-linux_x86_64/bin/avr-as
RANLIB=/opt/avr8-gnu-toolchain-linux_x86_64/bin/avr-ranlib
CC=/opt/avr8-gnu-toolchain-linux_x86_64/bin/avr-gcc
CXX=/opt/avr8-gnu-toolchain-linux_x86_64/bin/avr-g++
STRIP=/opt/avr8-gnu-toolchain-linux_x86_64/bin/avr-strip

When I try to link the project, I get the following errors:
[ 60%] Linking CXX static library libATmega328__T_LIB.a
/opt/avr8-gnu-toolchain-linux_x86_64/bin/avr-ar: CMakeFiles/ATmega328__T_LIB.dir/blink.cpp.obj: plugin needed to handle lto object
/opt/avr8-gnu-toolchain-linux_x86_64/bin/avr-ranlib: blink.cpp.obj: plugin needed to handle lto object

[100%] Linking CXX executable ATmega328__T_
/tmp/ccWiGx4b.ltrans0.ltrans.o: In function `main':
<artificial>:(.text.startup.main+0x0): undefined reference to `blink()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

It seems that the plugin for LTO isn’t being used correctly, even though I have specified -flto in the flags. Does anyone have an idea on how to resolve this issue?

so why is -fuse-linker-plugin' not in link flags?

What version of the tools are we talking about? The error may occur in cases where blink has uses that the compiler doesn't see. It that the case in your code?  Did you check that all required objects are being passed to the link stage?  Also using LTO code from a library has some limitations. If that is the case, just use them objects instead of piping them through some lib*.a for no reason.

I use avr8-gnu-toolchain-3.7.0.1796-linux.any.x86_64 from: https://www.microchip.com/en-us/tools-resources/develop/microchip-studio/gcc-compilers
I wanna create a template project, here is the code: https://github.com/Zombieanfuehrer/atmega328p-cxx-template
blink() is using avr c lib, nothing more quite simple example.

I changed my flags to this:
'tools.build:cflags=["-mmcu=atmega328", "-O2", "-ffunction-sections", "-fdata-sections", "-fno-exceptions", "-fno-rtti", "-flto", "-Wl,-flto", "-fno-devirtualize"]
tools.build:cxxflags=["-mmcu=atmega328", "-O2", "-ffunction-sections", "-fdata-sections", "-fno-exceptions", "-fno-rtti", "-flto", "-Wl,-flto", "-fno-devirtualize"]
tools.build:sharedlinkflags=["-Wl,--gc-sections",  "-flto", "-Wl,-flto"]
tools.build:exelinkflags=["-Wl,--gc-sections", "-flto", "-Wl,-flto"]'
Now I only got the undefined reference to `blink()' error.
Without flto it linking work

This work for me:

tools.build:cflags=["-mmcu=atmega328", "-O2", "-ffunction-sections",
"-fdata-sections", "-fno-exceptions", "-fno-rtti", "-flto",
"-ffat-lto-objects"] tools.build:cxxflags=["-mmcu=atmega328", "-O2",
"-ffunction-sections", "-fdata-sections", "-fno-exceptions",
"-fno-rtti", "-flto", "-ffat-lto-objects"]
tools.build:sharedlinkflags=["-Wl,--gc-sections", "-flto",
"-ffat-lto-objects"] tools.build:exelinkflags=["-Wl,--gc-sections",
"-flto", "-ffat-lto-objects"]

One more problem was, that i use conan profile in connection with cmake.
Unfortunately, the build flags from the conan profile are not automatically passed on to the CMake Build flags, which I then attached from the conan toolchain.cmake.
